# Do I really need the one line of JS code?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have this:

```
var output='<span class="price-month">';
for (var i in flexPay.PowerFlexPay) {
    output+=flexPay.PowerFlexPay[i].priceMonth;
}
output+='</span>';
document.getElementById('power-FP-month').innerHTML=output;
```

Do I really need `output+='</span>';`? I removed it and added `+ '</span>'` like so:

```
var output='<span class="price-month">';
for (var i in flexPay.PreferredFlexPay) {
    output+=flexPay.PreferredFlexPay[i].priceMonth + '</span>';
}
document.getElementById('preferred-FP-month').innerHTML=output;
```

And it still works. I just want to make sure I'm not breaking any standards.

Comment: Well, add a `console.log(output)` and have a look whether the HTML makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

So when `flexPay.PreferredFlexPay` has more than one property, you close the `span` element multiple times and do indeed "break standards". Most browsers will probably gobble the mess up without complaining, but not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need this line of code. Here is why:

I will explain it with a **simple example**:
Assume that you've got three elements in your `flexPay.PowerFlexPay` and the html of each element is `<div>`.

So with the first code snippet you'll get html code like this:

```
<span class="price-month"><div><div><div></span>
```

*Here the three divs are wrapped with the closing span element, because the span was added after the loop finished.*

With the second code snippet you'll get html code like this:

```
<span class="price-month"><div></span><div></span><div></span>
```

*Here for each div a span is appended, because the span was added in the loop.*

Comment: Where does the `div` come from?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should have left it where it was.  As it's now inside the `for` loop, you're outputting a closing `</span>` tag on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the closing span inside your loop or you'll have more than one. Your first example is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there are 2 situations, the second one closes the  inside the loop. Which will happen multiple times if you have more than one flexPay.PowerFlexPay item. Say there are 3 items, your output would be:

```
<span>... </span></span</span
```

In your first example it will only add the final  when the loop is complete leading to the correct html out:

```
<span>...</span>
```